# Google API Error - "The OAuth client was not found"

Tags: php, oauth, google-api

I tried to get statistics from google analytics with php without success. The code is following and the error is after when i trying to refresh the token

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Auth_Exception: Error refreshing the
>   OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_client",
>   "error_description" : "The OAuth client was not found." }'

```
$service_account_email = $this->settings->service_account_email;
$key_file_location = LOCALPATH.'plugins/google-api-php-client/client_secrets.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("GetStats");

$client->setAccessType('offline');
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_email,
  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
  $key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
   $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

return $analytics;
```

I think that the problem is in the google api console, but i can't catch it.

PS: If you have an easier option to get google statistics (with php or javascript) I will glad to try it

Comment: The problem was in the Google Search Console (Analytics). There have a menu Admin, then have to choose User Management and add permission (Read & Analyze) to your new mail from API Console (seems: 1234567-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com)